# multiprocessing.Process subclass works on Linux but not Windows

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, pickle, gasp

I'm trying to get [python-gasp](https://edge.launchpad.net/gasp-core) working on Windows, but when I do `import gasp; gasp.begin_graphics()` I get the following traceback:

```
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\gasp\backend.py", line 142, in create_screen

    screen.updater.start()

  File "C:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 104, in start

    self._popen = Popen(self)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 239, in __init__

    dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 162, in dump

    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump

    self.save(obj)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save

    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce

    save(state)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save

    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict

    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())

  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems

    save(v)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save

    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 725, in save_inst

    save(stuff)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save

    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict

    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())

  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems

    save(v)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save

    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 396, in save_reduce

    save(cls)

  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save

    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 748, in save_global

    (obj, module, name))

PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'multiprocessing.process._MainProcess'>: it's not found as multiprocessing.process._MainProcess
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error on Windows XP but not on Ubuntu Linux 9.04?

It looks like `screen.updater` is an instance of `Updater(multiprocessing.Process)` ([def](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Egasp-dev/gasp-core/main/annotate/head%3A/gasp/backend.py#L149)), if that helps. The file in question is at [http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~gasp-dev/gasp-core/main/annotate/head%3A/gasp/backend.py](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~gasp-dev/gasp-core/main/annotate/head%3A/gasp/backend.py#L142)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Updater` class has a member `screen`, which itself has a member `process` which receives the value of `multiprocessing.current_process()`.

When you call `updater.start()`, it tries to pickle the updater. This only happens on Windows because Linux uses `fork()` instead of pickling. However, the current-process object cannot be pickled and the exception is raised.

To fix this, you can remove the `process` member.