# Using multiprocessing inside decorator generates error: can't pickle function...it's not found as

Tags: python, multiprocessing, decorator, pickle

I came across a problem that I can't solve and it's associated with multiprocessing and use it inside the decorator.

When I'm calling the method `run_in_parallels` using multiprocessing I 'm getting the error:

`Can't pickle <function run_testcase at 0x00000000027789C8>: it's not found as __main__.run_testcase`

The call takes place inside the decorator, then followed the above-mentioned problem. At the time of calling the same method `run_in_parallels` without a decorator all working properly.

What is the reason of this problem?

---

**file:** w_PythonHelper.py

**desc:** Function 'run_in_parallel' is used to run multiple processes simultaneously. The first method, which will end operation stops the others.

```python
from multiprocessing import Process,Event

class ExtProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self, event,*args,**kwargs):
        self.event=event
        Process.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

    def run(self):
        Process.run(self)
        self.event.set()

class PythonHelper(object):
    @staticmethod
    def run_in_parallel(*functions):
        event=Event()
        processes=dict()
        for function in functions:
            fname=function[0]
            try:fargs=function[1]
            except:fargs=list()
            try:fproc=function[2]
            except:fproc=1
            for i in range(fproc):
                process=ExtProcess(event,target=fname,args=fargs)
                process.start()
                processes[process.pid]=process
        event.wait()
        for process in processes.values():
            process.terminate()
        for process in processes.values():
            process.join()
```

**file:** w_Recorder.py

**desc:** function 'capture' is used to grab a screenshot

```python
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time

class Recorder(object):
    def capture(self):
        ImageGrab.grab().save("{f}.{e}".format(f=time.time(),e="png"))
```

**file:** w_Decorators.py

**desc:** Running parallel a given function along with a method 'capture' of class 'Recorder'

```python
from w_Recorder import Recorder
from w_PythonHelper import PythonHelper

def check(function):
    def wrapper(*args):
        try:
            recorder=Recorder()
            PythonHelper.run_in_parallel([function,args],[recorder.capture])
            print("success")
        except Exception as e:
            print("failure: {}".format(e))
        return function
    return wrapper
```

**file:** w_Logger.py

**desc:** Main program (generates error)

```python
from w_Decorators import check
import time

class Logger(object):

    @check
    def run_testcase(self):
        # example function (runtime: 20s)
        for i in range(20):
            print("number: {}".format(i))
            time.sleep(1)

    def run_logger(self):
        self.run_testcase()


if __name__=="__main__":
    logger=Logger()
    logger.run_logger()
```

**file:** w_Logger.py

**desc:** Main program (works corectly)

```
from w_PythonHelper import PythonHelper
from w_Recorder import Recorder
import time

class Logger(object):

    def run_testcase(self):
        # example function (runtime: 20s)
        for i in range(20):
            print("number: {}".format(i))
            time.sleep(1)

    def run_logger(self):
        recorder=Recorder()
        PythonHelper.run_in_parallel([self.run_testcase],[recorder.capture])

if __name__=="__main__":
    logger=Logger()
    logger.run_logger()
```

What is the difference that these same methods presented in the two cases work differently?

---

EDIT:
Does anyone has an idea to solve this problem (is this Python bug)? If not, maybe someone knows a good way to capture screen shots when the application is running?

Actually I found similiar question: [multiprocessing.Process subclass works on Linux but not Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064533/multiprocessing-process-subclass-works-on-linux-but-not-windows)

The answer is: `To fix this, you can remove the process member.`, but how can I do this for my example.

While debugging the error occurs when calling `process.start()` in `run_in_parallel(*functions)`

---

EDIT2:
like **ivan_pozdeev** wrote: i can use wrapper as a function, but can't use it as decorator. I have many functions decorated by this decorator and the simpliest way is to use multiprocessing inside decorator. But unfortunatly I can't solve this problem. Maybe someone has already solved a similar problem. I would be grateful for any hint.

**'run_in_parallel'** function works like I want. Two or more functions run in parallel and the first function, which is completed forces the termination of second function. When I call **wrapper(function,*args)** then functions works ok, when I put this mechanism inside decorator I get **'can't pickle function...it's not found as'** error. Details can be found above

**My Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Interpreters\Python32\lib\pickle.py", line 679, in save_global
    klass = getattr(mod, name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run_testcase'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\EskyTests\w_Logger.py", line 19, in <module>
    logger.run_logger()
  File "C:\EskyTests\w_Logger.py", line 14, in run_logger
    self.run_testcase()
  File "C:\EskyTests\w_Decorators.py", line 14, in wrapper
    PythonHelper.run_in_parallel([function,args],[recorder.capture])
  File "C:\EskyTests\w_PythonHelper.py", line 25, in run_in_parallel
    process.start()
  File "C:\Interpreters\Python32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "C:\Interpreters\Python32\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 267, in __init__
    dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "C:\Interpreters\Python32\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 190, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Interpreters\Python32\lib\pickle.py", line 237, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\Interpreters\Python32\lib\pickle.py", line 344, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Interpreters\Python32\lib\pickle.py", line 432, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Interpreters\Python32\lib\pickle.py", line 299, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Interpreters\Python32\lib\pickle.py", line 623, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "C:\Interpreters\Python32\lib\pickle.py", line 656, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Interpreters\Python32\lib\pickle.py", line 299, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Interpreters\Python32\lib\pickle.py", line 683, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function run_testcase at 0x00000000027725C8>: it's not found as __main__.run_testcase
```

Answer (score 4):

The function you're passing to `Process.__init__()` is not picklable in Windows. Read [16.6 multiprocessing - Programming guidelines - Windows](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#windows) .

Regarding your error with a top-level function - I suspect the way you defined it, it is generated differently each time and thus is really "not the same object" in child. <strike>I suggest passing a simple top-level function that would call `run_testcase` using reflection if you really need this level of sophistication.</strike> Update: this didn't help

Update:

I made this work by undecorating `run_testcase`,`run_in_parallel` and `capture`. `@check` decorator was replaced with `def wrapper(function,*args)` with the same functionality:

```
import traceback
def wrapper(function,*args):
    try:
        recorder=Recorder()
        PythonHelper().run_in_parallel([function,args],[recorder.capture])
        print("success")
    except Exception,e:
        print("failure: "+traceback.format_exc(10))
```

main:

```
from w_Decorators import wrapper

if __name__=="__main__":
    logger=Logger()
    wrapper(logger.run_testcase)
```

Just as I thought - decorated objects are not picklable.

Comment: See my edits above. By the way, the logic in run_in_parallel() may be incorrect.

Comment: _@check decorator was replaced with def wrapper(function,*args) with the same functionality_ no, this is no the same functionality. Notice that I wrote that **I have to use** a decorator syntax. I just have a lot of methods that are decorated in such a way.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky, but I *think* what's happening is that `check` stores a reference to the unbound method when the class is defined. The working example uses a reference to the bound method `self.run_testcase` when you call `run_logger`.

I think the best thing is to try making `run_testcase` a top level function, rather than a method of a class.

Also, your `capture` function probably won't do what you expect - the current time will be stored when the function is defined, and every screenshot will be saved over the previous one. You probably want to call `time.time()` inside the function.

Comment: When I'm making `run_testcase` a top level function as You mentioned then I'm getting another error: `Can't pickle <function run_testcase_proc at 0x000000000273F9C8>: it's not the same object as __main__.run_testcase_proc`. Unfortunatly it must be a method of a class. I have to modify the currently existing decorator, to adopt the new functionality that will be performed in parallel with 'run_testcase'. `time.time()`function is a minor issue and only is used to keep some order, it could easily be a number, for example 1,2,3... The main problem was to modify the decorator.

Comment: @falek.marcin: From the multiprocessing docs: "bound or unbound methods cannot be used directly as the target argument on Windows" (http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing#windows)

Comment: There may be a workaround or alternative solution to modify the decorator. Does anyone have an idea how to solve it differently?

Comment: @falek.marcin: Maybe manually setting `__main__.run_testcase = function` before you send it to run_in_parallel will fool multiprocessing into thinking it's a top level function. But I wouldn't bet on it.