# How to implement a multiprocessing python decorator?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, pickle, wrapper

I want to write a wrapper for calling CPU-demanding functions in asyncio.

I want it to be used like this:

```py
@cpu_bound
def fact(x: int):
    res: int = 1
    while x != 1:
        res *= x
        x -= 1
    return res

async def foo(x: int):
    res = await fact(x)
    ...
```

At first, I wrote:

```py
def cpu_bound(func: Callable[P, R]) -> Callable[P, Awaitable[R]]:
    @functools.wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        executor =  get_executor() # This is a part where I implemented myself.
        return await loop.run_in_executor(
            executor, functools.partial(func, *args, **kwargs)
        )

    return wrapper
```

However, I had issues with pickling.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py",
> line 245, in _feed
> obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)   File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py",
> line 51, in dumps
> cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
> _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function fact at 0x000001C2D7D40820>: it's not the same object as **main**.fact

Maybe the original function and the wrapped one not having the same `id` is the problem?

So, is there a way to write such a wrapper?

I do know I can use `loop.run_in_executor`, but having such a wrapper can help a lot.

Comment: maybe you will have to run it as normal function `res = await cpu_bound(fact)(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe the original function and the wrapped one not having the same id is the problem?

In a way, yes. Before the function is sent to the target process it's pickled, which fails in your case, because the `func` object in the decorator's scope is different from the `fact` object in your main module, after rebinding by the decorator.
Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550577/pickling-wrapped-partial-functions#14550773) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370705/running-multiprocessing-inside-decorator) question for some background.

Based on these answers I created an example on how what you want can be achieved.
The trick is to create a picklable "runner" function, that the target process can use to look up your orginal function from some sort of registry (e.g. a dict...) and run it. This is of course just an example. You will probably not want to create your `ProcessPoolExecutor` in the decorator.

```py
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import functools

original_functions={}

def func_runner(name, *args):
    return original_functions[name](*args)

def cpu_bound(func):
    original_functions[func.__name__]=func
    @functools.wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args):
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(1) as pool:
            res =  await asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(
            pool, functools.partial(func_runner, func.__name__, *args)
        )
        return res

    return wrapper

@cpu_bound
def fact(arg):
    return arg

async def foo():
    res = await fact("ok")
    print(res)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(foo())
```

Comment: It works like a charm! Thanks!