# Python Multiprocessing Child Process Self Termination and PickleError

Tags: python, multiprocessing, decorator

I'm trying to learn the multiprocessing module and decorators. I have two questions about the code below:

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process

class async:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.func = function
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        p = Process(target = self.func, args = args, kwargs = kwargs)
        p.start()

@async
def printA():
    sleep(1)
    print("A")

def main():
    printA()
    printA()
    printA()

    #do more work

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

1. Right now I'm getting `PicklingError: Can't pickle <function printA at 0x00000273F97FF1E0>: it's not the same object as __main__.printA`
   I'm not sure how to fix this. I feel like this was working on my work unix machine, is it a Windows thing?
2. I want the child Processes to self terminate upon completion. I tried wrapping the function with `sys.exit()` at the end, and using that as the target for the Process, but `sys.exit()` doesn't seem to properly terminate the zombie processes. What would be the correct way?

I don't want to do a blocking `join()`, nor set `daemon=True`. The end goal would be someone could import this module, put @async on any function, and it would run in a separate process and then terminate itself when it reaches the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Pickling Error**: I could reproduce the issue. On Linux it works just fine, on Windows it doesn't. The issue seems to be the decorator which cannot be pickled correctly on Windows. Removing the decorator results in this working code (of course that's not what you want, but might convince you to try out a different approach of your design). There's also [this thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8304187/119861) with the exact same problem.

   ```
   from time import sleep
   from multiprocessing import Process

   def printA():
       sleep(1)
       print("A")

   def main():
       for i in range(3):
           p = Process(target = printA)
           p.start()

       #do more work

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       main()
   ```
2. **Zombie processes**: To avoid zombie processes you need to have the parent read its childrens exit codes, you **need** to run `join()` in the parent on the child processes to do that. You could do that in the decorator like this:

   ```
   class async:
       def __init__(self, function):
           self.func = function
           self.pool = []
       def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           p = Process(target = self.func, args = args, kwargs = kwargs)
           self.pool.append(p)
           p.start()
       def __del__(self):
           for p in self.pool:
               p.join()
   ```

This uses the effect that python does only one instance of `@async`, thus you can gather all the processes in `self.pool`. Note, that this is only run at the exit of the main process, as python would not drop the async instance earlier.

Comment: 1. Sorry about the delay thing, I edited it out. It was added after to test why it wasn't working. It still does not.

2. I tried using the Pool object, but it made the PicklingErrors worse when trying to use it in conjunction with a decorator.